# GUI Postman on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, gui, postman

I have problems with my installed Postman on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64 Version 6.3, build 9600).

First of all, I have downloaded and successfully installed (and also later removed) different versions of Postman: 6.1.4 (tried x86 and x64) and 6.1.3 (tried x86 and x64)

**Fact:**
I access my Windows Server 2012 R2 instance through a nested RDP like this

My computer -> Server 1 -> Windows Server 2012 R2

**Edit 1:**

Image depicting how I access my Windows Server 2012 R2.
[image]

Strange look and behaviour:
[image]

Same result with every tried Postman-version. Whats the problem here?
I do not know about any other application on the server that have this GUI problem.

Comment: Did you mean that when you use RDP to access this postman app of windows server 2012 r2, but it can't work normally? Can this app work normally on the local server 2012 r2? Did the issue happen on other app?

Comment: Hmm... If I try to explain it like this then: [my coumputer] -> [Server 1] -> [Windows Server 2012 R2, Postman]. From [my  computer], I use RDP to access [Server 1]. From Server 1, I use RDP to access [Windows Server 2012 R2]. I don't believe that RDP is a problem but I really don't know why the postman GUI is corrupted. Please see my updated question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same issue, and I solved it by setting the POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU environment variable, as described here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4594.

> For it to work you will have to add an environment variable POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU=true
>
> 1. Open advanced system settings
> 2. In the Advanced tab click Environment Variables
> 3. Add a new variable
> 4. Logout and Login back or Restart your PC

Note that my scenario is a little different: I'm running Server 2012 in VMWare Fusion 10.0 on a Mac OS High Sierra.  But my experience was identical to yours.

Comment: Great fix! I was able to set it on User environment variables (I don't have admin rights for the system ones) and did not need to reboot (restarting Postman was enough).